# Creating Instances from same SuperClass Object

Tags: java, object-oriented, inheritance

I have 3 subclasses (LowState, MediumState, HighState) which derive from the same superclass (State).

Within the superclass, State, I have declared several variables which need to be accessed and changed from the 3 subclasses.

Is it possible to instantiate these 3 subclass objects from the same *superclass object* so that they can all access the variables from the **same** object?

Alternatively, I can just declare the variables in each subclass and then pass the data between the objects. However, I'm concerned that this *chaining* method could get out of hand.

Comment: For the shared state, what you really want is composition, not inheritance, where the current children take the base class (which won't really be base class anymore) as their property during construction and the base class has accessors to give you access to the shared attributes. Then during object graph constructions you just need to make sure you inject the same instance of the base class into all three children, so when one children modifies its property, the change will reflect onto the remaining classes as well.

Comment: Unfortunately inheritance is a must as I'm using virtual methods in all 3 subclasses.

Comment: You can still make the three derived states to be children of some base class, but the shared state should be represented by *another class*, not the parent of the children, and same instance of the *another class* should be, as I have said in the first comment, injected into all instances of the children.

Comment: @DavidPacker, Ahhhh so you're suggesting storing those shared variables in their own object which is passed to the subclass objects?

Comment: @DavidPacker, would that be more sensible than just passing each individual variable? As there aren't many, it seems overkill to have a class nothing more than get and set methods.

Comment: While I am sure objects are passed by reference and thus if you inject same instance A into multiple instances B, mutating the state of instance A in any instance B will affect the state of instance A in all the remaining instances B, which accepted the same A instance, I think primitives are actually passed by value, or that is how most programming languages do that, so if you deconstruct the object and pass its values instead, you pretty much lost the shared state. But even then, I still don't like the design, it's flaky and unpredictable.

Comment: Superclass is just a "template" for its subclasses. Wheter if it's abstract or class every instance is single, there's no any suprainstance of Superclass ruling them all. That would be awesome but it's not the real purpose of inheritance in java. Sorry to say but I also think like David. You are approching to the problem from the wrong design.

Comment: May be with a Factory you could track every single instance by doing a cyclic reference: `instance  <> Factory <> instance`, but I don't know if it's good idea. Factory may work as Nexus. The point in common for any instance of State. Or to do a singleton of State and inject into every single substate. `substate <> singleton State <> substate`

Comment: Are the "variables within the superclass" instance variables or class variables?

Comment: @gnasher729 instance variables.

Answer (score 2):

> Within the superclass, State, I have declared several variables which need to be accessed and changed from the 3 subclasses.

That's what the **protected** modifier is for;

"# Me and my Subclasses ...".

> Is it possible to instantiate these 3 subclass objects from the same "superclass object" so that they can all access the variables ...

That you get from the protected modifier.

> ... from the SAME object?

Now *that* sounds like a strange (and dangerous) thing to want to do.

Why would you want to change these values?  You're potentially getting into all kinds of issues to manage changes from the different subclasses.

If you *really* want to do this, then the **static** modifier *might* get you want you want, but may well come with a heap of other, "new and exciting" problems to deal with (especially in unit testing/ mocking).

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to instantiate these 3 subclass objects from the same
>   "superclass object" so that they can all access the variables from the
>   SAME object?

No. But you can instantiate from a `State` that has its members defaulted to particular values, and consequently your subclasses will all have the same values.

```
public class State {
   protected int stateValue = 1;
}

public class SubState extends State {
   // stateValue will be '1' here...
}
```

If you used 'composition' rather than inheritance, you could instantiate your 'SubState' objects *referencing* the same 'State' object. However you'd have to be wary of sharing that object across multiple subclassed object, and that doesn't seem very safe or intuitive.

Noting your comment below, *composition* would provide that means of sharing state change e.g.

```
public class SubState(State state) {
   // 'state' could be shared across multiple substates here...
}
```

and you don't need the superclass/subclass relationship that you're referring to.

Comment: But if one of the subclass states changed the value of stateValue, surely the others wouldn't see the update.

Comment: See my edit above...

Comment: Hmmmm do you think it would just be safer to pass the values between objects?

Comment: I would suggest it's perhaps more *intuitive*